# Problems with new server accessing ldap and mail server/relay (connection timeout and can't contact)

Tags: linux, ldap, opensuse, sles

I'm on OpenSUSE 12.3, and setup a mail relay under mail server settings (posix) via yast.

I try to send a mail and get timed out:

```
2013-09-27T15:19:08.745282+01:00 myserver postfix/qmgr[12258]: 2973BE49E4: from=<>, size=2705, nrcpt=1 (queue active)
2013-09-27T15:19:08.748700+01:00 myserver postfix/qmgr[12258]: B66A7E49A1: from=<root@myserver.mysite.com>, size=1979, nrcpt=1 (queue active)
2013-09-27T15:19:38.779794+01:00 myserver postfix/smtp[17650]: connect to mailserver.com[123.456.78.9]:25: Connection timed out
2013-09-27T15:19:38.779811+01:00 myserver postfix/smtp[17651]: connect to mailserver.com[123.456.78.9]:25: Connection timed out
2013-09-27T15:19:38.783206+01:00 myserver postfix/smtp[17650]: 2973BE49E4: to=<ctu.data@mysite.com>, orig_to=<root@myserver.mysite.com>, relay=none, delay=90908, delays=90878/0.01/30/0, dsn=4.4.1, status=deferred (connect to mailserver.com[123.456.78.9]:25: Connection timed out)
2013-09-27T15:19:38.784639+01:00 myserver postfix/smtp[17651]: B66A7E49A1: to=<my.name@mysite.com>, relay=none, delay=252675, delays=252645/0.01/30/0, dsn=4.4.1, status=deferred (connect to mailserver.com[123.456.78.9]:25: Connection timed out)
```

Ldap logs via the php app, show error:

```
Array
(
[0] => An unexpected failure occurred
[1] => 0x1: Failed to retrieve DN for account: enphsrob [0x51 (Can't contact LDAP server): ldap://ldap.mysite.com]...)
```

I've copied ldap and mail settings from a working server on SLES 11, firewall is also the same (HTTPS/HTTP/SSH only).  I have to be whitelisted for the mail server and was told I was whitelisted.  For ldap I don't know if that is also the case.  While I wait to find out, I want to see if it's something I can fix.  Thanks in advance for any replies!

Answer (score 0):

In this case I was right.  External factors were blocking the server from accessing the ldap and mail servers. When they said they had enabled access, they actually had not and I had to chase it up.